# How to convert (bake) animation of Follow Curve frames into objects?

Tags: animation, rigging

I want to make different objects from the frames that come from the Follow Path.
In this case, it is desirable that the curve could be transformed.

In order not to go into a long explanation, I want to repeat what he does in this video, but in Blender (approximately from 5 to 9 minutes).

https://youtu.be/7YtdWJ-qlYM?t=293

Comment: Interesting question.. but in this particular case, could the effect be more easily achieved, and with better feedback, by using _Array_ and _Curve_ modifiers, with appropriate adjustments to the curve's thickness and tilt? ... Maybe not..